# Extending Image Class

Tags: php, image, silverstripe, extend, silverstripe-4

Is there a way to extend the image class in Silverstripe 4 like this?

```
class MyImage extends Image {
    public function generateRotateClockwise(GD $gd)    {
        return $gd->rotate(90);
    }

    public function generateRotateCounterClockwise(GD $gd)    {
        return $gd->rotate(270);
    }
```

I didn't find anything on the Silverstripe webpage.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the Injector to rewrite the class that is loaded when SilverStripe asks for `Image`, but with Image it's not recommended. If you wanted to, you'd do this:

```
# File: mysite/_config/injector.yml
---
Name: myinjectorconfig
---
SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector:
  SilverStripe\Assets\Image:
    class: MyImage
```

And your class would look like the example in your question.

---

Instead if you want to add two new PHP methods you can use an Extension:

```
use SilverStripe\ORM\DataExtension;

class MyImageExtension extends DataExtension
{
    public function generateRotateClockwise(GD $gd)
    {
        return $gd->rotate(90);
    }

    public function generateRotateCounterClockwise(GD $gd)
    {
        return $gd->rotate(270);
    }
}
```

Then apply it to Image with configuration:

```
# File: mysite/_config/extensions.yml
---
Name: myextensions
---
SilverStripe\Assets\Image:
  extensions:
    - MyImageExtension
```

This adds the two public methods to wherever an Image class is used.